# Convert new column from data of two column as pairs

Tags: r

Having data into columns which every value is separated by comm how is it possible generally the values which are in the flattened_column1 column as column names and as value for every row the values of column flattened_column? Here is a working example but I would like to make it more generic in order to have NA when a specific value/column name doesn't not exist in a new row or a new column name is availiable into another line.

```
# Your data structure
data <- structure(list(flattened_column = "'mac-addr', '2.1', 'mac-addr--3fwef', '00:21:12:b4:12'", 
                        flattened_column1 = "'type', 'spec_version', 'id', 'value'"),
                   row.names = c(NA, -1L),
                   class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# Extracting values and creating a new data frame
values <- strsplit(gsub("'", "", data$flattened_column), ", ")
col_names <- strsplit(gsub("'", "", data$flattened_column1), ", ")

new_data <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(values), nrow = nrow(data), byrow = TRUE))
colnames(new_data) <- unlist(col_names)
```

Comment: Can you please give an example when you want NA to be inserted? Does a string then have an empty place, e.g. `"'mac-addr', '2.1', '', 'mac-addr--3fwef', '00:21:12:b4:12'"`?  In this case are both strings still symmetric, with the same number of entries?